# jQuery - pause animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

My website has a news section in the format of squares that animate alot like the Metro UI. The square animates once every 5-10 seconds (random) and swaps between the text and picture.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7k9n0hxg/2)

I now want the animation to immediately switch to the text-stage when the user mouse-overs, and remain there until mouse-out. When the user mouse-outs the animation can either resume with any delay that's left from before the mouse-in, or instantly switch to the picture-stage. I prefer the first, but any solution works.

I tried doing something with `.hover` but I'm not sure how to best pause/resume animations. Cheers.

**HTML**

```
<div class="news-container">
    <div>
        <div class="news-window">
            <div class="date"><span>05</span><div>Sep</div></div>
            <div class="news-tile" id="1">
                <div class="news-pic" style="background-image:url('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000532546226/dbe5f0727b69487016ffd67a6689e75a.jpeg');"></div>
                <div class="news-title"><div>News Title</div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="news-window">
            <div class="date"><span>28</span><div>Aug</div></div>
            <div class="news-tile" id="2">
                <div class="news-pic" style="background-image:url('https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/155293403-cat-adoption-checklist-632x475-e1354290788940.jpg');"></div>
                <div class="news-title"><div>News Title</div></div>
            </div>                          
        </div>
        <div class="news-window">
            <div class="date"><span>17</span><div>Aug</div></div>
            <div class="news-tile" id="3">
                <div class="news-pic" style="background-image:url('https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/99233806-bringing-home-new-cat-632x475.jpg');"></div>
                <div class="news-title"><div>News Title</div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.news-container {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;

}

.news-window {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #EFEFEF;
    width: 230px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.news-tile {
    width: 230px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
}

.news-pic {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.news-title {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #5D697B;
    color: orange;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: table;
}

.news-title div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.news-window .date {
    width: 50px;
    height: 56px;
    background: orange;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0.5;
    line-height: 1.25;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.news-window .date span {
    font-size: 28px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    move(1);
    move(2);
    move(3);
});

function random(){
    return ((Math.random() * 5000) + 5000);
}

function move(i) {
    $("#" + i + ".news-tile").delay(random()).animate({top: "-200px"}, 600, 'easeOutCirc');
    $("#" + i + ".news-tile").delay(random()).animate({top: "0"}, 600, 'easeOutCirc');
    window.setTimeout(function() {move(i) }, 500);
}
```

EDIT: Fiddle had a problem. Fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `.delay()` use `setTimeout`, which is more appropriate in case of cancelling the animation on `hover()`.

> The `.delay()` method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—`.delay()` is not a replacement for JavaScript's native [**`setTimeout`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

[Reference](https://api.jquery.com/delay/#entry-longdesc)

Also, it would be more convenient to use classes instead of `id` attributes in your situation.

I'd make it this way (**updated**):

```
$('.news-window').each(function(i, el){
    el.timer = setTimeout(function(){moveUp.call(el)}, random());
}).hover(function(){moveUp.call(this, true)}, moveDown);

function random(){
    return ((Math.random() * 5000) + 5000);
}

function moveUp(x){
    var that = this;
    $('.slide', that).stop().animate({top:"-200px"}, 600, 'swing');
    clearTimeout(that.timer);
    that.timer = x || setTimeout(function(){moveDown.call(that)}, random());
}

function moveDown(){
    var that = this;
    $('.slide', that).stop().animate({top:"0"}, 600, 'swing');
    clearTimeout(that.timer);
    that.timer = setTimeout(function(){moveUp.call(that)}, random());
}
```

**NOTE**, I added `slide` class to each of the `news-tile` elements (as you have more sections with `news-tile` class).

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hyo655zm/)

Comment: This is very neat, however if you mouse-over long enough, it will `moveDown`. It needs to stop all animation (for that tile) until mouse-out. Ideas?

Comment: @Chris , you could simply pass something like `true` as a parameter for `moveUp` method, then setTimeout for `moveDown` method only if the parameter is *falsy* : [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hyo655zm/)